# $H \unlhd G$, $\pi:G \to H$ is a group homomorphism with $\pi(h)=h$. Show that $G \cong H × G/H$

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups, group-homomorphism, quotient-group, direct-product

Let $H$ be a normal subgroup of a group $G$ such that there is a group homomorphism $\pi:G \to H$ with $\pi(h)=h$ for all $h \in H$. Prove that $G$ is isomorphic to $H × G/H.$

I don't know how to solve this. Any help is appreciated.

And if you know some abstract algebra book that deals with this kind of problem please mention, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As $H$ is normal, we have a short exact sequence of groups
\begin{equation}
1\xrightarrow{\hspace{1cm}}H\xrightarrow{\hspace{.5cm}\iota\hspace{.5cm}} G\xrightarrow{\hspace{.5cm}p\hspace{.5cm}} G/H\xrightarrow{\hspace{1cm}}1
\end{equation}
and our hypothesis is that there exists a map $\pi:G\to H$ such that $\pi\circ\iota=\operatorname{id}_H$. What you are trying to prove is sometimes referred to as "the splitting lemma", you can find a proof [in these notes](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/grouptheory/splittinggp.pdf), Theorem $3.2$.

Answer (score 1):

We claim that $\phi:G\to H\times G/H$, $$\phi(g)=(\pi(g),Hg)$$
for all $g\in G$ is an isomorphism.

- $\phi(g_1g_2)=(\pi(g_1g_2),Hg_1g_2)=(\pi(g_1)\pi(g_2),Hg_1Hg_2)=(\pi(g_1),Hg_1)(\pi(g_2),Hg_2)=\phi(g_1)\phi(g_2).$
  So, $\phi$ is a homomorphism.
- Let $e$ be the identity of $G$. Then, the identity of $H\times G/H$ is $(e,H)$.
  If $\phi(g)=(e,H),$ then $\pi(g)=e$ and $Hg=H\implies g\in H\implies\pi(g)=g$.
  So, $K_\phi=\{e\}$ and $\phi$ is injective.
- Let $(h,X)$ be any element of $H\times G/H$, where $h\in H, ~X\in G/H$. Then, $X=Hg$ for some $g\in G$.
  Consider $x=g\pi(g^{-1})h\in G$. We have, $$\phi(x)=(\pi(g)\pi(\pi(g^{-1}))\pi(h),Hg\pi(g^{-1})h)$$
  Observe, $\pi(g^{-1})\in H\implies \pi(\pi(g^{-1}))=\pi(g^{-1})=\pi(g)^{-1}$ and $Hg=Hg\pi(g^{-1})h$ since $H\unlhd G\implies g\pi(g^{-1})hg^{-1}\in H$.  $~~~~~(\because Ha=Hb~$ iff $~ab^{-1}\in H)$
  Hence,
  $$\phi(x)=(h,X)$$
  So, $\phi$ is surjective.

Therefore, $$G\cong H\times G/H$$

Answer (score 0):

The kernel of $\pi:G\to H$ is
$$K=\{x\in G~|~\pi(x)=e\}.$$
Let $g\in G$ and $\pi(g)=h\in H$. Then,
$$\pi(gh^{-1})=\pi(g)\pi(h^{-1})=e\implies gh^{-1}\in K\implies g\in K H.$$
So, $G\subseteq K H$ and $K H\subseteq G$.
Therefore, $G$ is the internal direct product of $K$ and $H$ since $$G=KH, ~H\unlhd G,~K\unlhd G,~K\cap H=\{e\}. $$
Using the relation between internal and external direct products,
$$G\cong K\times H$$
By the second isomorphism theorem,
$$K/(K\cap H)\cong KH/H\implies K\cong G/H\implies K\times H\cong G/H\times H.$$
Therefore,
$$G\cong H\times G/H$$